# Entity Framework Code First Reference constraint issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having problems with my model and trying to delete records. I have reduced it to try and show the issue I am having

I have a entity called `CollectedBags` with an Id and name.

I then have a entity called `BankingRun` which contains a list of `CollectedBags`

`public virtual List<CollectedBags> Bags { get; set; }`

This model automatically adds a relationship between the two, and in the database it adds a column to collectedbags to reference the BankingRun.

The problem occurs when I want to delete the BankingRun without affecting the CollectedBags table at all. A CollectedBags record doesn't always belong to a BankingRun.
Anything I try to delete a record results in a conflict between the two tables obviously, but my lack of knowledge with entity framework is leaving me stuck without writing some SQL to physically remove the Banking Run id in CollectedBags

```
public class CollectedBags
{
    public long CollectedBagsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BankingRun
{
    public long BankingRunId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTimeVisited { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CollectedBags> Bags { get; set; }
}
```

I am then trying to delete a BankingRun after its been created with multiple CollectedBags

Comment: Can you post more code, please? Also, the error message would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

With Fluent API use this code:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.UserDetail)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

This is just an illustration, but the important thing here is the `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

It will prevent that when you delete one entity all others related get deleted as well, basically.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unless I am missing something, when I did this it caused an error when creating my `BankingRun` saying that it couldn't cast a list of `CollectedBags` to type `CollectedBags`. I don't fully understand how your solution works but I don't want `CollectedBags` to be an optional dependent within the `BankingRun`. I NEED the relationship when the `BankingRun` exists, however I need it to go away completely when wanting to remove one.

Comment: As I said, this is an illustration. You'll need to adjust the code accordingly, but the thing here is the cascade on delete;